# Delete some characters from mysql row

Tags: mysql

I need to delete `~\NewFolder1\` from the field `photo` in my table `new` but the query doesn't work

```
UPDATE `new` SET `photo`=REPLACE(`photo`,'~\New\','')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need escape '\' by adding additional '\'

```
UPDATE `new` SET `photo`=REPLACE(`photo`,'~\\NewFolder\\','')
```